# Can cherry picking really old commit from seperate branch to master cause problems?

Tags: git

Short story: We had an issue, where customer reported some feature they wanted developed year ago stopped working. The problem is, the feature was indeed developed, but put into separate branch and then not merged into master, so the feature in fact was never on live enviroment, only on testing.

So now I am tasked with fixing it. I cherry picked the commit with the feature, and there were no merge conficts. But is there some pitfall, like some new functionality using the old constructors etc and it did not get picked by the git merge?

Only sensible thing I can think of is thorough test of the app, but that poses huge timesink or ship it anyway and wait if some bug pops up.

Comment: You have an automated test suite, don't you? If yes, then why would a "thorough test of the app" (a good idea IMO) be a huge time sink?

Comment: @TheLaw: especially at smaller businesses, where you don't have a full QA department and a bunch of testers at hand, it pays off to automate as many tests as possible, **because** you don't have limited resources, not "despite". Nevertheless that would probably not solve your problem in full, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It seem like a perfectly fine question to me.

Comment: @AK_is_curious: "Can something cause problems" is not a real question.  Any tool or technique can cause problems if it is used improperly.

Answer (score 4):

When you add new code to an existing application, it can contain bugs - no, that is an understatement, it **will** contain bugs. Additionally, this has also a certain risk of causing issues in the existing part of the application, not just in the new part.  And it does not matter if that code is written manually line-by-line, or if it is pulled into your master branch using an tool like Git.

Even if you tested the feature in isolation (and "in another branch" counts as "in isolation"), and it showed up no bug any more, there is no guarantee integrating the code into the app won't cause additional issues overlooked by the isolated tests.

Here is a simple example: lets say your web application has a functionality of displaying number of total visits of a user. Now, the new feature added in a separate branch was a button to reset the counter used in that functionality to zero. It was tested in that branch and worked at that time. Unfortunately, in between in the master branch, someone decided to remove the original feature, but keep the counter and give it different meaning. Now it is used for the number of allowed login trials, where "zero" will forbid any further login attempt. When you now cherry pick the feature, technically it will work - just not the way as intended: the counter will be reset to zero, and next time this particular user cannot login any more. Sure, this example may look somewhat artifical, but I guess you get my point.

So the answer is definitely **YES**, cherry picking something into master branch can cause problems. My point is, this has nothing to do with Git, Git saves you neither from syntactical not from semantical issues of code integrations.

The only way to reduce the number of bugs before bringing the code into production is proper quality assurance and testing, which includes also integration testing. Maybe you have an automated test suite for this, but for new code with new features you probably need to extend that test suite, and not everything can be handled by automated tests. So you should expect some testing effort for this.

If you decide to *"ship it anyway and wait if some bug pops up"* is an economic decision, that noone here can take away from you. Sometimes "time to market" is more important than quality, sometimes it is the opposite. However, I guess your customer won't be pretty happy when you tell him "here is the feature you expected", and when he tries it out for the first time, it will blow directly in his face.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are risks with merging or cherry-picking an old commit into the current state of affairs.

The first risk is that so much has changed in the affected files in the mean time that git can't find all the places where the changes need to be applied or that conflicting changes have been made. This should normally result in merge conflicts, but I can't guarantee that that will always be the case.

The second big risk lies in the fact that git does not understand the language/structure of the files you are merging. Especially with an older commit, it is possible that the merge itself does not show any conflicts but the changes are such that the compiler or interpreter does not accept the code anymore or that an external component makes assumptions about the code that are not valid anymore. This can only be mitigated by properly testing the result of the merge.

Answer (score 0):

The older the code is, and the further away from your current code, the more problematic it is to just cherry pick and hope for the best.

I would recommend that you act as if you were developing the feature yourself right now, and taking code from that old branch just saved you the work of typing it.

I wouldn't even call it "pitfalls" if something goes wrong; if this comes from a really old branch then it would be quite unexpected if it just works.